# jQuery: $.post not working, $.get works

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly, I did look at related posts, but none of them quite stoops down to my stupidity levels. Its my first time working with web technologies and I'm trying to work with Ajax/JQuery and Django.
Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                                
    $('#result').ajaxError(function() {                                       
       $(this).text('Triggered ajaxError handler.');                           
    });                                                                       
    $('#b').click( function() {                                               
        codes = $('#code').text();                                            
        $.get("/questions/compile",                                           
            function(data){                                                   
                alert("data saved" + data);                                      
            });                                                                   
    });                                                                       
});
```

Now this code works fine and I get a alert box as expected. But when I change $.get to $.post, I get ajaxerror. I did try using $.ajax with appropriate values, but get same problem as $.post . Firing up Firebug, shows an error at line 5252 in jquery.js. That line is

```
xhr.send( type === "POST" || type === "PUT" || type === "DELETE" ? s.data : null );
```

I'm not sure how to debug any further. And since I'm not sending any data, $.post should work just as well as $.get. Now go ahead and point out my stupidity. Cheers.

Comment: oh, btw, I did try the code on both Firefox and Chrome. So I guess that rules out browser issues.

Comment: Maybe the server doesn't allow POST requests to this url.

Comment: Non-ajax/non-jquery POST methods work just fine. Does jQuery require making some additional changes to my server configuration?

Comment: its not just an issue with your version of jquery is it? If the error is with jquery.js - have you tried redownloading jquery? or including the google hosted one?

Comment: Try the "Net" tab on firefox. Is there a new POST and does the response look ok?

Comment: Are you sure you modifying your server side code as well while you make change to the request type to handle the post request?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#b').click( function() {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/questions/compile",
                    data: "codes="+codes.text(),
                    success: function(data){alert("Data Saved!: "+data)}
    });});
```

and on the /questions/compile file, you need something like

```
echo $_POST['codes'];
```

any other questions?

Comment: I get exactly the same response. Replacing 'POST' with 'GET' in your code works just fine. But with POST, i get ajaxerror.